In R: raster:brick() read NetCDF file for one location produces error: cells are not equally spaced
I wrote a script to download SST data as NetCDF and convert it to a data.frame in R. I use raster::brick() to read the data and convert it with raster::as.data.frame(xy = T) to a data.frame.
If I do this for a data set with at least 2 latitude and longitude values (additionally to the time dimension), it works as desired. But as soon as there is only one latitude or longitude value (i.e. data along a line or at a point), I get the error Error in .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...) :  cells are not equally spaced; you should extract values as points.

What can I do to read a NetCDF file at a point/line using raster::brick?
I did not find any information on how to do what the error message suggests and extract the values as points. How could this be done?
Is there any alternative to quickly read NetCDF as a data.frame?


NetCDF is a very flexible format, so it would help if you could point us to one of these files, then we know we are working with the same data you are.
There is an ncdf4 package for R which lets you read general NetCDF data files but you'll have to understand the underlying structure to make sense of it all.

I've been experimenting and the terra package can read a one-dimensional netCDF I made, with warnings instead of errors, so you do get your data back. Terra is more supported than the raster package these days so you should maybe start using it?

Thanks! I used the ‘terra‘ package before, but it imported the data incorrectly, i.e. in the reversed order. I am writing a small package that automatically downloads data for a location and imports it into R, therefore I'd like to have one method that works for different files. I download data from NOAA Coral Reef Watch via ERDAP from here. To download a small example file, here's a link.

It seems like raster and terra both derive the spatial resolution when at least two grid cells are present. They obviously fail to do so with only one cell since there is no delta x/y and they do not seem to consider the res information given in the metadata: geospatial_lon_resolution=0.05 and geospatial_lat_resolution=0.05. If your desired output is a data.frame, you should be able to construct this yourself with ncdf4::ncvar_get() with time/longitude/latitude/CRW_SST as input.

Thanks! I want to use a generic function that could be used with NetCDF from different sources but sometimes the order in which the variable values are associated with time and position differs so I'd need each data set to figure this out first. For data covering an area this works well with raster, but for data for one point, I had to adapt my script to download .csv which is less efficient but works.
